# What if a glfw function is called without a window?

Tags: c++, glfw

I was trying to call `glfwGetKey` after `glfwTerminate`, of course this function won't be performed, but I was wondering why hadn't VS warn me that no function found, as in this case, glfw window has been destroyed.

Is it something I need to do manually to pop the warnings out? I thought the reason `glfwGetKey` didn't response to my query is it was queried outside of window. So I tried to access `glfwPollEvents` before the creation of window, no warnings popped out as well, and no response from it as well. It looked like glfw lib has been 'silenced'.

I know window is always bound to context, but is it legal to call glfw function without a window ?

Comment: Does registering a `glfwSetErrorCallback()` beforehand output anything in that case?

Comment: Why do you expect that warning? `glfwGetKey` is a function that always exist. For Visual Studio to know that you have created a window **and** haven't called `glfwTerminate` before calling it, it would have to simulate your whole program, and even then it wouldn't be able to know exactly.